# RESTful webservices consumption in Windows store apps

Tags: web-services, rest, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I want to use a RESTful web service in Windows Store app ,I surfed a lot on internet but i have not got any sample code project through which i can refer & learn how to consume JSON based restful services in Windows store apps.If anyone knows please help me.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this one as a reference:

[Developing Enterprise Windows* Store Apps using RESTful Web Services](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/developing-enterprise-windows-store-apps-using-restful-web-services)